# Android application Packages help?

Tags: android, package

Ok, so it might be a stupid question that is very obvious... anyway, I am making a new application and I wanted to know if I should make a package for every category of objects,

for example: Monsters, PowerUps, Powers, FrameWork(where I make classes that I implement from) etc.

I am using canvas and a thread class to handle what happens inside the canvas(lockcanvas, unlock and post etc.)

So, should I make everything in one package or few packages, and will it be harder or do I need to know something to use these packages? Thanks!

Comment: What kind of benefit are you hoping to get out of multiple packages?

Comment: Just so it would be more organized and maybe even easier to write codes in the main activity when i call each of the other packages' classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's entirely up to you how you group your classes.  In terms of coding, it makes little difference as Eclipse will work everything out for you.  Instead, consider how you can use packages to help you quickly go to the right place when you return to your code in six months time to correct a bug.

IMHO, your proposal seems to result in a few too many packages for comfort.  I don't know how complicated your code is, but if you've only got a handful of classes per package, that's probably a bit too fine.  Probably better to break your app into larger chunks of functionality.  It's also worth spinning common "helper" or "utility" classes into their own package too.

As with any aspect of coding style, opinions will vary.  But I found the following article to be well argued...

[Package by feature, not layer](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do;jsessionid=0BF4844350780B6F55476E1137FF4893?Id=205)

Answer (score 0):

You could get the same organizing effect you are looking for by using folders inside the package to group code without all the hassle of additional packages.  Unless you have a special technical requirement for multiple packages I would try to keep things as simple as possible.

Comment: Thanks, but i saw some tutorials and read some books about it and they used many packages, however, when i try to use few packages i get many errors using the codes. I think that i would try using the folders that you suggested, but is there certain names that i have to use when i make folders, like in the drawable folders?